Get totals for top 5 elements in GROUP BY, and then the rest of the groups in a single total
I have a question. I have the following scheme
CREATE TABLE 'redirect3' (
  id INT,
  short_url_id INT,
  browser SYMBOL capacity 256 CACHE,
  platform SYMBOL capacity 256 CACHE,
  os SYMBOL capacity 256 CACHE,
  referrer_domain VARCHAR,
  country SYMBOL capacity 256 CACHE,
  language SYMBOL capacity 256 CACHE,
  time TIMESTAMP
) timestamp (time) PARTITION BY MONTH WAL;

You can generate some pseudo-random data for this table like this:
INSERT INTO redirect3 (
    id, 
    short_url_id, 
    browser, 
    platform, 
    os, 
    referrer_domain, 
    country, 
    language, 
    time
)
SELECT
    x AS id,
    rnd_int(1, 100, 0) AS short_url_id,
    rnd_symbol('Chrome', 'Firefox', 'Safari', 'Edge', 'Opera', 'Internet Explorer', 'Brave') AS browser,
    rnd_symbol('Windows', 'Mac', 'Linux', 'Android', 'iOS') AS platform,
    rnd_symbol('Windows 10', 'macOS', 'Ubuntu', 'Android 11', 'iOS 14') AS os,
    rnd_str('google.com', 'facebook.com', 'twitter.com', 'linkedin.com', 'instagram.com', 'youtube.com', 'reddit.com') AS referrer_domain,
    rnd_symbol('US', 'UK', 'DE', 'FR', 'JP', 'IN', 'BR') AS country,
    rnd_symbol('en', 'es', 'de', 'fr', 'ja', 'hi', 'pt') AS language,
    timestamp_sequence(to_timestamp('2023-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 1000000000) AS time -- 1 second intervals
FROM long_sequence(1000, 123456789, 987654321) x;

For example, I would now like to display the top 5 browsers and then others with the remaining values.
I see 2 options for this
I use SELECT count(), browser FROM redirect3 and truncate and sum after the 5th value.
I fetch the top 5 and the total number.
With the pseudo random data above, the results should be



Browser
Total




-Others-
256


Firefox
160


Internet Explorer
152


Edge
152


Safari
141


Chrome
139



I would actually like to do the same for other fields like os and country.
Does questdb allow me to do all of this in a query or how would you implement it?

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Thanks! I often see SQL question showing just the CREATE TABLE statement and I thought that would suffice, but added extra information for the example

We can do something like this (this query can be executed at the demo instance https://demo.questdb.io)
with totals AS 
(
select 
symbol
, count() as total from trades
), ranked AS (
SELECT *, rank() over (order by total DESC) as ranking from totals
)
select case when ranking <= 5 THEN 
symbol
 else '-Others-' end, SUM(total)
from ranked order by 2 DESC;

For the table in the question, it would be
with totals AS 
(
select 
browser
, count() as total from redirect3
), ranked AS (
SELECT *, rank() over (order by total DESC) as ranking from totals
)
select case when ranking <= 5 THEN 
browser
 else '-Others-' end, SUM(total)
from ranked order by 2 DESC;


You can try this:
    WITH browser_counts AS (
    SELECT 
        browser, 
        count() AS total 
    FROM 
        redirect3 
    GROUP BY 
        browser
),
top_browsers AS (
    SELECT 
        browser, 
        total 
    FROM 
        browser_counts 
    ORDER BY 
        total DESC 
    LIMIT 
        5
),
other_browsers AS (
    SELECT 
        '-Others-' AS browser, 
        sum(total) AS total 
    FROM 
        browser_counts 
    WHERE 
        browser NOT IN (SELECT browser FROM top_browsers)
)
SELECT * FROM top_browsers
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM other_browsers; 


Put ORDER BY total DESC at the end, to get the desired result.

This would also work, but reading the EXPLAIN plan, and after testing both methods, the rank() seems to perform a bit better
